# how to get rid of the warning "captured variable is disposed in the outer scope"

Tags: c#, task

For below code I am getting warning for `client` saying `captured variable is disposed in the outer scope`, what's is meaning for this and how can I get rid of it?

[image]

```
using (var client = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(""))
            {
                //Loop through each batch in the chunked list
                var concurrentTasks = list.Select(r=>
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        await Push(r, client);

                    })).ToList();
                //complete all the tasks.
                await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
            }


 private async Task Push(List<R> r, DeviceClient client)
    {
      await client.SendEventAsync(new Message(e));
}
```

Comment: Just a false positive in this case. you can [locally disable such a warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case it is clear that the warning is a false positive. Because the execution of all the Tasks is awaited at `WhenAll` the `client` will not be disposed early. You could locally disable the warning as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings).

HOWEVER, in this case there is another issue. By calling the `Task.Run` for just a simple async method call, you're wrapping the inner `Task` in another `Task`. That's not necessary and a bit of a waste. Especially since you're not in a synchronous scope, you could just write

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(
    list.Select(r => Push(r, client)).ToList());
```

Comment: Ow, nice find.....

Answer (score 1):

`client` is being used as parameter inside the task, but disposed outside the task.

Effectively this could mean its disposure is not aligned with its usage causing potential nasty time based exceptions, due to the fact possibly multiple threads are involved.

Since you're awaiting all calls you should be safe, but if you use a nested method inside which doesn't, you run into this issue again.

The compiler is warning against this pattern.

To resolve you should create and dispose the client within the task or disable and ignore the warning.

@Johns addition to assign the variable to a task local variabele might also get rid of the warning, but keep in mind that does not resolve the potential issue, which in your case is unlikely to happen.

Comment: You addressed the "what's is meaning for this" part but not the "how can I get rid of it". The use of `await` means that the potential issue the warning is about will never occur. I believe that assigning `client` to a local variable inside the block and using that in its place should clear the warning. This is a scenario where a code comment would be appropriate, because it should explain WHY something is being done, rather than WHAT is being done.